# In the sentence "I watched the balloon rise", "rise" is in what verb tense? And why?

Tags: tense, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund, to-infinitive, bare-infinitives

> I watched the balloon rise.

I understand that "rise" in this sentence is not in the 3rd person, because otherwise it would have "s" and it doesn't.

Is it infinitive? The why not "to rise"? I kinda understand it but I can't explain to another person why.

Comment: It is an infinitive, a so-called bare infinitive. Google **bare infinitives** for a full explanation and lots of examples.

Comment: "Watch" is a catenative verb that takes a bare infinitival complement here. Other verbs of sensory perception that can also take bare infinitival complements include "feel", "hear", "notice", "see" and "watch", though most can take _to_-infinitivals as well, e.g. "We saw him to be an imposter". I don't know why; it's just the way these verbs work.

Comment: Incidentally, the intervening noun phrase "the balloon" is object of "watched", but only the understood (semantic) subject of "rise". In other words, "the balloon" is not syntactically subject of the infinitival clause.

Comment: Thank you. I got it now.

Answer (score 2):

> *I watched the balloon rise.*

"Watch" is one of a few verbs of sensory perception that can take a bare infinitival complement, but not a *to*-infinitival complement.

Most of the other verbs of sensory perception can take both a bare and *to*-infinitival complements, cf. *I saw him leave* and the passive *He was seen to leave*.

There are plenty of resources on the 'Net, where you can find more information about other verbs whose complements are restricted to one or the other, or that can take both kinds of infinitival complement.

Comment: Thank you. I think I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

Other examples of this structure or form.

- He **saw** the man leave.
- They **heard** the door bang.
- She **felt** her pulse race.
- We **watched** the house burn.
- I **listened** to the music play.
- He **looked** at the squirrel run.
- We **experienced** the situation worsen.
- I **perceived** the the bell ring.
- We **noticed** the door open.

So, those are some of the verbs that can work this way. They all involve having a direct experience of some thing.

If you take the direct object and replace the present simple verb with **when it + the verb**, the **meaning** is clear.

- I saw **the man leave**. = I saw the man **when he left**.
- They heard **the door bang**. = They heard the door **when it banged.**

**The examples above where the third person plural s is not used, are just like**:

- We suggest **you leave**.
- I recommend **he go**.
- It is important **he play today.**

However, in the first group of examples, **the main verbs are all in the simple past**. Except for stage or movie script directions, the **simple present** here *would be odd*, though the continuous would not:

- He sees the man leave. [theatrical script]
- He saw the man leave. [real life]
- **I'm seeing** the man leave. [real life, as he leaves]

This used to be called subjunctive in English. Many linguists would call this a bare infinitive today.

Personally, I would argue that these examples parse like this:

- He saw//the man leave

And that "the man leave" is simply a direct object phrase in the form of a subject plus bare infinitive as with verbs like recommend or advise or suggest.

Same as: I watched//the balloon rise.

These can also be analyzed as noun clauses:

For example, from the linked text:

The sales clerk suggested she put the dress on hold.

[noun clauses](https://esllibrary.com/blog/recommend#:%7E:text=Some%20verbs%20in%20English%20have,the%20focus%20of%20the%20suggestion.&text=These%20verbs%20are%20all%20used,he%20or%20she%20should%20do.)

To summarize, some verbs of observing and experiencing function in a way similar to the verbs advise, recommend and suggest where the noun phrase verb in the third person singular does not take an s.